# What does $\sum_n P\lbrack|X_n|\ge an\rbrack=\infty$ in problem 22.7 from Billingsley mean?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I'm working on problem 22.7 from Billingsley's Probability and Measure (3rd. Ed.), but I'm not sure about the notation used. It says

> ... show that $\sum_n P\lbrack|X_n|\ge an\rbrack=\infty$ ...

I wonder if that means that $an$ is to be held fixed throughout the summation or if it is supposed to vary with the summation index. If it's not fixed, I wouldn't know what to do because I would need to prove that it doesn't decrease sufficiently fast for the series to converge.

Any ideas?

Comment: The way it’s written, $an$ varies, so you do have to show that the terms do not decrease sufficiently quickly. To give a hint what to do, we would need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my copy, it's problem 22.8 - summarizing the relevant part of the question:

Given $\{X_n\}$ i.i.d. with $E |X_1| = \infty$, use that for positive $X$, that 
$$ E X = \int_0^\infty P(X\ge t)\, dt, $$ to  show  the above  sum diverges for all $a$.

Suggestion:  WLOG, $a>0$. Write $X = |X_1|$, and consider
$$ \infty = E X  = \int_0^\infty P (X \ge t )\, dt = \sum_{n = 0 }^\infty \int_{na}^{(n+1)a} P( X \ge t) \, dt.$$

What's an upper-bound for  each integral in the sum?

Then use $ P( |X_n| \ge b  ) = P ( X \ge b )$, for all $n$, and all $b$.

Comment: As @EikeSchulte wrote above, $n$ certainly varies...